# ¿Cómo importo la librería stdio.h del lenguaje C?

Tags: c

Escribí **mi primer programa en C**, que es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hola mundo\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Pero me saltan los siguientes **dos errores**:

**(1)** *Se han detectado errores de #include. Actualice el valor de includePath. El subrayado ondulado está deshabilitado para esta unidad de traducción (C:\Users\DELL\Documents\VSC_Workspace\Curso_C\Untitled-1.c).*

**(2)** *No se puede abrir el archivo origen (código de error "stdio.h").*

Entonces decidí **descargar la librería y meterla en la carpeta** *Curso_C* como otro archivo de código C para que así la encontrara. Sin embargo, el primer error persistía en el proyecto *Untitled-1.c* porque, a pesar de ya poder abrir la librería al estar este en la misma carpeta (por eso **el segundo error se corrigió**), **el código de la librería llama en su código a otras librerías que tampoco tengo.**

Antes de empezar a importar librerías como un loco, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de importar la librería "limpiamente" o, como segunda opción, importarla a través de un link hacia un servidor (como se hace por ejemplo en el desarrollo web con JS, el cual permite importaciones locales y no locales, por así decir, a través de un link).

Trabajo con Visual Studio Code como IDE.

Gracias y espero su respuesta.

Comment: Que IDE estas utilizando??

Comment: Visual Studio Code. ¿Desea que lo incorpore a la pregunta o no lo ve necesario?

Comment: Bueno, nunca esta de más saber con que IDE trabajas !

Comment: Y que compilador estas utilizando? `stdio.h` lo tiene que traer tu compilador.

Comment: Ok, entonces me falta el compilador. Pues me pongo a ello y a ver qué sale. Gracias. Es que pensé que ya lo había instalado junto a VSC dado que me obligó el IDE a instalar una extensión para C (pensé que era el compilador, pero será que no)

Comment: ¿Me recomiendan algún compilador?

Comment: Aunque se refiere a C++, [en el sitio de vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler) podés leer lo siguiente: _VS Code es ante todo un **editor** (...). La extensión C/C++ no incluye un compilador o depurador (...)._

Comment: Entiendo que esos errores te los está dando el editor, y que aún no has intentado compilar. Cuando usas VSCode y el plugin para C, el editor intenta analizar el código a medida que lo vas escribiendo para señalarte posibles problemas, pero para ser capaz de hacer eso necesita leer los .h que vayas incluyendo, etc. El que no sea capaz a leerlo es indicio de una instalación incorrecta del compilador C o del plugin de autocorrección de VSCode.

Comment: Instalé igualmente esta extensión: C/C++ Compile Run
¿No hace es un compilador? Al menos, lo venden como tal

Comment: No, no necesariamente es un compilador. Más bien es una extensión de VSCode que le permite "controlar" al compilador de modo que puedas ejecutarlo sin salir de VSCode. Pero el compilador debes instalarlo por otra vía, fuera de VSCode, y quizás decirle a VSCode de algún modo qué compilador es el que tienes instalado

Comment: ¿Y dónde consigo el compilador para C? Porque he leído sobre un tal MinGW, pero hablan de él como estuviera obsoleto

Comment: No creo que esté obsoleto (aunque es ciertamente muy antiguo). Parece que es el reomendado desde la propia [documentación de VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) para trabajar con C/C++ desde windows. Otra opción sería el compilador de microsoft, ([Visual Studio C](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/vs/features/cplusplus/)) pero creo que ese es un producto comercial (aunque tiene alguna licencia gratuita para estudiantes, o quizás para todo el mundo, no sé)

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias, He comenzado con la instalación de MinGW y veré si, al final, el error era debido a la falta del compilador o si hay algo más de por medio

Comment: Pues al final ha funcionado MinGW, pero en el output sale el siguiente error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Untitled-1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status. Imagino que debo estar ejecutando sin permisos de administrador, pero tampoco sé cómo otorgar esos permisos a Visual Studio. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Por cierto, ABULAFIA, puedes poner tu respuesta de que falta un compilador y te doy el voto positivo, si quieres. Porque el problema original está resuelto